# Plot multiple scatter graph using certain range of columns as x axis

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, graph

I have a data frame as shown below:

[image: DataFrame]

This data is saved as the variable "filterWage".

This data frame contains the columns Country.Code, Series.Code and range of columns from  X1992 to X2016 (please bare in mind I could not fit the whole X1992 to X2016 columns thus only up to x2003 is shown on the image).

The objective is to plot this range of columns from  X1992 to X2016 as the x-axis and the value of these columns as the y-axis, for all three Country.Code in the same plot using ggplot.

Desired outcome: ( please note that the image is merely a rough sketch and the values are indeed meaningless)
[image: Desired outcome - please ignore the incorrect values]

This is the output using dput:

> dput(filterWage)

```
structure(list(Country.Code = c("LIC", "HIC", "MIC"), Series.Code = c("SL.EMP.WORK.ZS", 
"SL.EMP.WORK.ZS", "SL.EMP.WORK.ZS"), X1991 = c("20.9370976972316", 
"81.0876932275574", "35.5281394063616"), X1992 = c("20.5114136551512", 
"81.1351300966788", "36.1635880437505"), X1993 = c("20.309137441086", 
"81.2165339365649", "37.1943086793304"), X1994 = c("20.5295488411938", 
"81.3404039783739", "37.8383615292357"), X1995 = c("20.6817100202905", 
"81.6237989883691", "38.6979499878051"), X1996 = c("20.6371916830899", 
"81.8361588628956", "39.5068057398044"), X1997 = c("20.286823787263", 
"82.140587079514", "40.0301927962263"), X1998 = c("20.3800244386649", 
"82.4387485706644", "40.1689926776"), X1999 = c("20.764112251619", 
"82.7303105606365", "40.3738643748966"), X2000 = c("20.5693165666214", 
"83.0691410634413", "40.7860042844162"), X2001 = c("20.6682554227926", 
"83.204549665691", "40.192062080076"), X2002 = c("20.8364224185492", 
"83.3236267668205", "40.5335866623684"), X2003 = c("20.9073131339766", 
"83.3872571313811", "41.139037517746"), X2004 = c("20.9741288400519", 
"83.4445860257721", "42.2303006080139"), X2005 = c("20.6931847813705", 
"83.7017144881631", "43.2626386469723"), X2006 = c("21.0482961178193", 
"84.0126990344844", "44.4032188240263"), X2007 = c("21.3789126998501", 
"84.3099847840774", "45.3836159214118"), X2008 = c("21.713214795025", 
"84.5962197639565", "46.1155674823931"), X2009 = c("21.9697284827288", 
"84.5498700141843", "46.8058440395641"), X2010 = c("22.3676584297642", 
"84.614095791104", "47.6604416403023"), X2011 = c("22.383629219082", 
"84.8323447185694", "48.6708213003224"), X2012 = c("22.6398140927035", 
"85.1570293953982", "49.2830314898562"), X2013 = c("23.0490884430663", 
"85.3153737253528", "49.5549460027067"), X2014 = c("22.8973838689315", 
"85.4292150603637", "50.0215575751258"), X2015 = c("22.9079191238809", 
"85.6087846399656", "50.3787072273931"), X2016 = c("22.8986911131366", 
"85.7321179083769", "50.5504090357067")), row.names = c(166L, 
332L, 498L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you please put the data not as image but as code? Preferably the output of `dput(DATA_NAME)`.

Comment: How does this plot relate to your data? The values don't range from -2.5 to 4.5, but from 20.28682 to 85.73212...

Comment: I had the caption of the image as "please ignore the incorrect values" but somehow the caption was never shown. Sorry for the misunderstanding and thank you for the answer, it was indeed the correct answer I was in search of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `tidyr` and `dplyr` (as well as `ggplot2`):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

filterWage %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("X"), names_to = "years", values_to = "value") %>%
  dplyr::mutate(years = as.numeric(gsub("X", "", years)), value = as.numeric(value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = years, y = value, colour = Country.Code))+
  geom_line()+
  theme_minimal()
```

I can't test this because I don't have your data, but it should work.

The idea is that I turned all those columns into a single pair of columns, one storing the former names and one storing the values. This way, your data is in the long format, not the wide. `ggplot` always likes taking data in the long format. Then, `mutate()` turns this both columns into numeric variables, removing the "X" in the years.

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Sorry but it says "geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?" and when plotted no line or data is shown on the graph.

Comment: This is the outcome: https://ibb.co/9YvCPDZ . Also, how would one go about posting the data

Comment: What do you mean by "positioning the data"?

Comment: Since you said "I can't test this because I don't have your data". How can I share the data?

Comment: As I commented on your question, giving the output of `dput(filterWage)` is an excelent way.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I do apologise for my lack of competence

Comment: No worries, don't beat yourself up! It wasn't lack of competence in any way. Now you know it for next time!